# Issue while configuring API routes with path parameter using serverless framework

Tags: serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I'm relatively new to the AWS serverless and serverless framework. I have created the following API routes and tested them using the offline plugin and it is working as expected. But when I'm trying to deploy this using `sls deploy` to my AWS it is throwing me the following error.

```
Error:
CREATE_FAILED: ApiGatewayResourceNoteTimestampVar (AWS::ApiGateway::Resource)
Resource handler returned message: "A sibling ({note_id}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 400, Request ID: c12acedd-d270-4988-bb01-427d058aa76c, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: 803cf4a6-5bc4-48c5-6648-2b0de46528f6, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

My *serverless.yml* look likes this

```
functions:
  add-note:
    handler: apis/add-note.handler
    description: POST /note
    events:
      - http:
          path: note
          method: post
          cors:
            origins: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
  update-note:
    handler: apis/update-note.handler
    description: PATCH /note
    events:
      - http:
          path: note
          method: patch
          cors:
            origins: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
  delete-note:
    handler: apis/delete-note.handler
    description: DELETE /note/{timestamp}
    events:
      - http:
          path: note/{timestamp}
          method: delete
          cors:
            origins: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
  get-notes:
    handler: apis/get-notes.handler
    description: GET /note
    events:
      - http:
          path: note
          method: get
          cors:
            origins: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
  get-note:
    handler: apis/get-note.handler
    description: GET /note/{note_id}
    events:
      - http:
          path: note/{note_id}
          method: get
          cors:
            origins: "*"
            headers: ${self:custom.allowedHeaders}
```

I don't know what's wrong with the code as it is working well locally?
I'd appreciated a help here.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you're changing a route from one lambda function to another. It's a consequence of how API Gateway and Lambda interact.

You'll need to first remove the route from the function, deploy the stack, and then add the route to the new function.

It works locally because your API Gateway emulator doesn't actually use CloudFormation - which is what Serverless uses to deploy your application.

Answer (score 0):

hi maybe do you need add the parameter in your path note_id on serveless.yml
some like this example.

```
        request:          
            parameters:       
              paths: 
                note_id: true
```